# Codeigniter won't connect to one table only

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Running PHP 5.3 and SQL Server 2008 R2 using sqlsrv driver to connect.

Codeigniter 2.2

So I have been using codeigniter for a couple years now and this is the first time I have run across this problem.  I have a table in my database named 'update_times' which is a log table for data updates I load daily, it has around 2000 records in it and is indexed on the columns I query against.  My database has 60 or so tables and 'update_times' is the only table I am unable to select anything from with codeigniter.

I have done a bunch of tests:

1. I ran a record count for every table in the database and every other table was correct except 'update_times' table which returned 0 records
2. I can query(select) from the table in Management Studio with no problem.
3. I can also select from update_times table using sqlsrv php function sqlsrv_query, I return records using this method
4. I am unable to select using active_record select or query method from codeigniter (I tried it in multiple controllers/models)

Here's the weird part, I can insert, update and delete using the active record functions.  It is only the select where I am having the issue and only on this table.

I tried rebuilding the indexes and rebuilding the entire table as well but nothing helped.  So I am left stumped.  I was going to just create a new table with a new name for update_times but I really want to find the problem in CI so that I know what to do if it happens again.  It's almost like CI is blocking the select for some reason.

I now have created a table with a different name with that same structure and I am unable to query it the same as the update_times table. I am still stumped.

Here is the table structure of update_times:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[update_times](
[ut_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[table_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[start_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[end_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[records] [int] NOT NULL,
[emp_id] [int] NULL,
[dates_requested] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ut_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any help would be great or suggestions on how to narrow the error.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using and what is the code you are trying to use to select? Is the table name unique from the rest in any way? (e.g. only name with an underscore?) Or maybe one of the characters is weird (my cousin likes to use use an omega sign instead of u's in random stuff).

Comment: @ToniW I am using Codeigniter 2.2.  I've used a bunch, even SELECT 1 FROM update_times, and still get 0 results.There is nothing I can see that would do that, I'm not using any special characters.  I will add the table structure above an an edit.  It's just codeigniter because I can use sqlsrv and it returns the proper results.

Comment: did you checked the schema of other tables?

Comment: @Rifky the schema is dbo same as all my tables, any other ideas?  Really no clue what is happening

Comment: did you check the database name on config and the one you use on sql ent manager.

Comment: @Rifky yes everything is the same.